# Running .NET Core unit tests with SQL Server in a Docker container: sqlException: handshake Problem

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, docker, containers

How can I run unit tests in a .NET Core Test project with a SQL Server running in a Docker container? I have set up a SQL Server in my Dockerfile and can successfully run the unit tests if I manually build and start the Docker container, navigate to the "Test" folder in the container and run the tests with "dotnet test".

However, if I try to run the tests by starting the container with a command, I always get an error message.

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Success)

The connection string looks like this:

```
SqlConnection sqldr = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=host.docker.internal;User ID=sa;Password=abcDEF123#;Encrypt=false;MultiSubnetFailover=true;TrustServerCertificate=true");
```

And here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest as sqlserver

USER root

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y 
ENV SA_PASSWORD=abcDEF123#
ENV MSSQL_PID=Developer
ENV MSSQL_TCP_PORT=1433 

#copy all the sql files to the docker container
#COPY /Database/Scripts /database/ 
RUN ((/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & ) | grep -q "Service Broker manager has started") 

COPY . .

# install the dotnet environment
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0
```

That is the command how I build the container:

```
docker run -d sqlserver_sqltoolsservice
```

That is the command which generates the error:

```bash
docker run -p 1433:1433 sqlserver_sqltoolsservice /bin/bash -c "cd Data.Test && dotnet test"
```

I also tried to add the following to the dockerfile:

```
RUN sed -i 's/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN sed -i 's/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256/g' /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf

RUN sed -i 's/MinProtocol = TLSv1.2/MinProtocol = TLSv1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN sed -i 's/CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

Comment: Aside... as per the [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) documentation, the sa password is passed in using the `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD` environment variable, not `SA_PASSWORD`.

Comment: Why are you installing `dotnet-sdk-6.0` inside the SQL Server container itself instead of inside a seperate application container? If you must use `USER root` to install extra components then be sure to specify `USER mssql` towards the end of the Dockerfile to restore the correct user. The SQL Server service is not meant to be running as `root`.

Comment: Have you read through [using an entrypoint.sh and setup.sql scripts to create a database](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/tree/master/linux/preview/examples/mssql-customize) yet? How you're trying to initialize a database is all wrong, you definitely shouldn't be trying to run the SQL Server service during the Dockerfile's image build phase.